# Qt Creator cannot set breakpoint on Linux

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, qt-creator, ubuntu-10.04

I can succesfully compile and start debugging of my multi-thread application from within Qt Creator.
However, if I start debugging with a breakpoint set, then the application stops immediately with message

```
The gdb process terminated
```

My setup is:

- Ubuntu Linux 10.04
- Qt Creator 2.6.2
- gdb 7.1

I looked at the gdb console, which only reports the message *The gdb process was ended forcefully*.

If I run the same binary file through gdb in console everything works fine and I'm able to either debug and set the breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter *Options->Debugger->GDB* and disable *Use dynamic object type for display*.